# incorrect picture when loading splash screen

Tags: android, android-splashscreen

I'm trying to make a splash screen using this guide: [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#java)

Only the picture doesn't look like that at all
I can't convert svg to xml because of some moments in svg (writes in asset vector ERROR @ line 4:  is not supported and ERROR @ line 7:  is not supported)
The picture that is used in png format
is the style code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash12</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

the picture is not my splash screen, but it looks the same (I can't show mine because of the nda). A picture was taken from the guide on YouTube, but there he decided through group in xml, which I can't do (see above why)
[image]

Comment: did you mean your image is cutting?

Comment: @HanifShaikh Yes, it looks different than on versions below 12

Comment: Yes, splash screen API is currently not providing good view of splash photo, SVGs. Follow this content for your splash image -> https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#dimensions

Comment: @MDEV I was just doing this guide, but I can't convert my svg to xml( or can I use pure svg for android?

Comment: @steind.VY Use this site to convert your SVG to XML -> https://shapeshifter.design/ This site is just for splash screen animation. You can create an animated splash screen and export it to AVD.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <group
    android:pivotX="95"
    android:pivotY="28"
    android:scaleX="0.5"
    android:scaleY="0.4">
```

Use this is your vector image. and if the image still cutting then change the value inside **pivotX** and **pivotY**.

also please check this video after 13 min that help you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Loo4i5IrZ4Y